# How to load specific date format into BigQuery

Tags: database, date, google-bigquery, schema, google-cloud-platform

When loading a .csv file into **BigQuery** with dates with this format `DD/MM/YY` it doesn't work, if I specify the schema for the table and I select Date Format.

However, if I don't specify the schema and I choose **Automatically detect** it works and converts the date format into `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Is there any possibility of convert the date into the right format manually and specify the name for that field?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, there is no way to control date formatting from the load API. You can load data into `STRING` first, and then use Standard SQL's `PARSE_DATE` function to parse it using any custom format.